# Trying to remember book title: dystopian world where people have to have sex every day to survive

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

This book is set in a city where frequent sex (without pleasure) is the only way to survive. Then, somebody falls in love. May be first book of a trilogy. Would have been written before 2001.

I should say it is not really a “graphic” book, more like a philosophical book. Male author I think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art, or even just the colour of the cover?

Comment: Well, if humans aren't required, _The Mote in God's Eye_ comes close. Moties die after a certain duration of not being pregnant.

Comment: @Spencer Dying from not being pregnant is actually a thing in some types of animals - mustelids like ferrets only ovulate if stimulated by breeding activity, so if not stimulated they can succumb to the effects of prolonged estrogen exposure, which results in bone marrow toxicity and death. Weird, but true, see the section labeled *Hyperestrogenism* under Urogential disorders in [this scientific article on ferret biology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7170204/) (WARNING - images of dissections, and medical procedures in the article).

Answer (score 4):

Is this ["The World Inside" by Robert Silverberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Inside)? It's not a perfect match by any means.

> The Urbmons are a world of total sexual license where men are expected to engage in "night walking"; it is considered very rude to refuse an invitation for sex.